# SQL Server Scripting the Database with Identity and Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to script my entire database using SSMS. I noticed that it doesn't
script the identity columns or the primary key. Is this correct seems very odd.
is there a tool anyone can recommend that will accomplish this task?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DRIVERS]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BADGENUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MOBILETEL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HOMETEL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDRESS1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDRESS2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDRESS3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TOWN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [POSTCODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BADGEEXPIRES] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [COMMENTS] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [DISABLED] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ONSHIFT] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PIN] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SCHOOLSOK] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EMAIL] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The `ID` column should be auto increment identity and primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the script it did generate for one of the tables?  In my experience, SSMS Generate Scripts will include the primary keys, but they are not part of the column definition.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
[a] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[b] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

becomes this when scripts are generated

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
[a] [int] NOT NULL,
[b] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[a] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The primary key is still defined, but the generated script uses the formal, detailed syntax.

Comment: Yes I should have encluded the script.